# Best way to navigate throught a JSON in Node while validating the path

Tags: node.js, json

I'm trying to get some info out of a API call in Nodejs, structured something like a JSON:

```
  { 
   "generated":"2019-11-04T09:34:11+00:00",
   "event":{ 
      "id":"19040956",
      "start_":"2019-11-16T11:30:00+00:00",
      "event_context":{ 
         "sport":{ 
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Soccer"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm not sure about the presence of none of these fields(Json could be incomplete).
Is there a better way to get the value of "name" in *JSON.event.event_context.sport.name* **without an ugly if** to not get errors like "cannot get field 'sport' of undefined"?
Currently, I'm doing

```
if(json.event && json.event.event_context && json.event.event_context.sport) {
 return json.event.event_context.sport.name;
}
```

**Is there a better way?**
Thank you!

Comment: You better to ask [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=json%20navigate) about questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is also an interesting package that will allow more conditions on searching json :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspath

```js
let getNested = (path, obj) => {
  return path.split(".").reduce( getPath, obj);
}
let getPath = (path, key) => { 
    return (path && path[key]) ? path[key] : null 
}

let test = {
  "foo": "bar",
  "baz": { "one": 1, "two": ["to", "too", "two"] },
  "event": { "event_context": { "sport": { "name": "soccer" } } }
}
console.log(getNested("none", test))
console.log(getNested("baz.one", test))
console.log(getNested("baz.two", test))
console.log(getNested("event.event_context.sport.name", test))
```

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by saying "I'm not sure about the presence of none of these fields"?
i don't understand what your'e trying to achieve.

Comment: The Json could be incomplete: the "sport" could be missing as same as the whole "event" part

Comment: I think we are missing some information and it's impossible to help you solve your problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question. that was the result of an API call, so I'm not sure about what I will recieve

Comment: If i understand correctly, name will always appear in the object - but you don't know which level it will be in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash get to get a potentially deeply-nested value, and also specify a default in case it doesnt exist.

Example

```js
const _ = require('lodash');
const my_object = {
   "generated":"2019-11-04T09:34:11+00:00",
   "event":{ 
      "id":"19040956",
      "start_":"2019-11-16T11:30:00+00:00",
      "event_context":{ 
         "sport":{ 
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Soccer"
         }
      }
};
_.get(my_object, 'event.event_context.sport.name');  // "Soccer"
_.get(my_object, 'event.event_context.sport.nonExistentField', 'default val');  // "default val"
```

Article: https://medium.com/@appi2393/lodash-get-or-result-f409e73e018b

Comment: Thanks, that's a good solution! Do you know a solution without using lodash? If not iIcould stick to this

Comment: You could write your own implementation of this (similar to what lamtacvu did in his response), or the other option is the `obj && obj.event && obj.event.event_context && ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using a function to check object keys like :

```
function checkProperty(checkObject, checkstring){
    if(!checkstring)
        return false;
    var propertiesKeys = checkstring.split('.');
    propertiesKeys.forEach(element => {
        if(!checkObject|| !checkObject.hasOwnProperty(element)){
            return false;
        } else {
            checkObject= checkObject[element];
        }
    })        
    return true;
};

var objectToCheck = { 
   "generated":"2019-11-04T09:34:11+00:00",
   "event":{ 
      "id":"19040956",
      "start_":"2019-11-16T11:30:00+00:00",
      "event_context":{ 
         "sport":{ 
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Soccer"
         }
      }
   }
}
if (checkProperty(objectToCheck ,'event.event_context.sport.name'))
    console.log('object to find is : ', objectToCheck .event.event_context.sport.name;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there are better ways!

For example, you could use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get)'s [`get()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) method to reach a nested value.

```js
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };

_.get(object, 'a[0].b.c');
// => 3
```

**But there is also a native solution.**

Currently (11.2019) only Babel can handle this.
I am speaking of **Optional chaining**. It's new in the `Ecmascript` world.

Why I like it? Look here!

```js
// Still checks for errors and is much more readable.
const nameLength = db?.user?.name?.length;
```

What happens when `db`, `user`, or `name` is `undefined` or `null`? With the optional chaining operator, JavaScript initializes `nameLength` to `undefined` instead of throwing an `error`.

If you are using Babel as a compiler then you could use it now.

Related link: https://v8.dev/features/optional-chaining